# Search and print word in line in python

Tags: python

I want to search for second column in text file and dont want to print the line if it matches specific word:

```
Title = line.split(" ")
TitleCheck =["apple" , "banana" , "mango"]
        if not Title[1].startsWith(for word in TitleCheck)
        print Title[1]
```

but it is giving error

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: you're using `if`, where is the indent and colon?

Comment: and `(for word in TitleCheck)` isn't the Python's syntax...do you want to use list comprehension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is invalid syntax.

try:

```
if not Title[1].startswith(tuple(TitleCheck))
```

Check the spelling of startswith. camelCase is incorrect.